# Why do I get a "Metafile not found" error when trying to compile a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, compilation

I had to **rebuild** a project in my application.

I created a **new project**, created each file, and copied the contents of each file into the new project one at a time making all the necessary changes.

Now when I try to **compile** the project, it gives me three errors:

- The **metafile** c:\projects\project1\CustomerModule\bin\Debug\CustomerModule.dll could not be found.
- **Application Definition Element** could not be given by the library project file.
- The **project file** has invalid properties.

Clicking any of these does nothing.

**What are these errors telling me? What do I need to change to get my application running again?**

**New info:** If I do a "rebuild" on just the project, I only get the second two errors, so these seem to be the original issue, but what is the library project file and what properties are invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on [this forum question](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/30728.aspx).

Basically the thing I did wrong was **copy images** from a directory in one module to a directory in another module *within the Solution Explorer*. **Don't do this.** Instead, copy them from the Windows Explorer into the Solution Explorer, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Click **add a reference** and browse for the dll file you want to use.

You may have to **rebuild** the dll for it to work.